# Saving the value returned by a function after importing the function in python

Tags: python, function

I called a function (`carlabels`) from a file in python and want to take the value returned by the function as an input to use in the later parts of the code. I was able to import the function to a new python file and am able to print the values returned. How do I save these values in a text file to use them further?

```
#detected_cars.py
import cartracker                       #this code is for detecting the cars
import cartracker2                      #slight modification on cartracker    
width = 3296                            #dimention to capture  
height = 2472                           #dimention to capture
gray = cv2.CreateImage(sz, 8, 1)        #create an image of specified dimention
new_fc = 1

def carlabels(carinfo):
    labels=[]
    r=60
    for (tag,xy,orient,err,wl,sq) in carinfo:
        xy2= (int(xy[0]+r*math.sin(math.radians(orient))),int(xy[1]-r*math.cos(math.radians(orient))))
        labels.append((xy,xy2,str(tag)))
    return labels

if new_fc:
    carinfo = cartracker.Analyze_captured_near_gate(gray, area=[width, height], th_factor=0.5, single_edge=0)
else:
    carinfo = cartracker2.Analyze_captured_near_gate(gray, area=[width, height], th_factor=0.5, single_edge=0)

labels = carlabels(carinfo)
```

When i perform:

```
print labels #i can see the id's of the car displayed.
```

But, when i try to import the value returned by the function as shown below, the value is not displayed

```
from detected_cars import carlabels
tag_id_nd_coordinates = labels
print tag_id_nd_coordinates
```

Comment: If you just want to use the value later in the code there's no need to save it to a file. Just call it (`carlabels()`) when you need it, or store it as a variable and use that (`labels = carlabels()` then (`do_something_with(labels)`).

Comment: @Holloway what if i want to access a specific element from the value returned by the function? Because when i run the code mentioned in the question, the value is printed along with the output, i would like to save the value to a text file, so that i can play with it later,

Comment: What is the value that is returned? If you need the output that was `print`ed in the function, you probably want to change your code so that it returns it instead.

Comment: @Holloway the identity of the cars and the x and y coordinates .

Comment: Could you add the `carlabels` function to the question?

Comment: @Holloway. There is a section of code downstream to this one, which calculates 'carinfo'. The value is later stored as labels=carlabels(carinfo)

Comment: Could you check the indentation of your code? At the moment the `if` block is a syntax error, I'd guess that part wasn't supposed to be indented.

Comment: I have reindented the if/else block to how I imagine it should have been. Please check it's correct and revert it if it's not how your code is.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns a list. Assign it to something and then just treat it as any other list.

```
#detected_cars.py
def carlabels():
    return [1, 2, 3]
```

Then

```
>>> from detected_cars import carlabels # note no .py extension when importing
>>> labels = carlabels()
>>> print(labels)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> print("sum of labels: ", sum(labels))
sum of labels: 6
>>> print('First label: ', labels[0])
First label: 1
```

The line `from detected_cars import carlabels` doesn't execute your carlabels function. It only makes the function available in that file.

If you want access to the `labels` variable you created in your other script, you should be able to use `from detected_cars import labels` and then use `labels` as a list.

Comment: I tried doing this before. Unfortunately the value is not displayed to screen.

Comment: what was displayed? Could you add the code you tried to call it with to the question?

Comment: I am sorry i didnot understand.

Comment: @HarikrishnanR, which part?

Comment: this comment                                                                     
"@HarikrishnanR, edited to add alternative import."

Comment: When i try to 'print labels' before 'return labels', the value is printed to screen. What i need is to take this value of labels and use this as an input for another section of code.

Comment: There is not `print`  statement in your function. If you want to print the values after importing you need to call `print labels` somewhere.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to do this, the way i am importing is added to the above code.

Comment: @HarikrishnanR Try `from detected_cars import labels` instead of `from detected_cars import carlabels`. At  the moment you are importing the function not the labels list.

Comment: thank you for your comments. Now the identity of the cars and the coordinates are imported and printed on the screen. What if i want to save the value returned by labels to an array to use it later ?

Comment: How much later? If it's within the same script, just hold onto the labels reference. If it's in a new session, have a look at something like shelve in the python standard library.

Comment: Its in the same script. The idea behind the whole code is, once the cars having specific identity reaches the front of gate (cars near the gate can be identified by the coordinates of the car), the gate will be opened. I wrote a python-ardunio code for controlling the gate. Now once i have the list of the cars and there coordinates and  if they are allowed to enter the garage, then the door will open. So i need the list of cars to be saved in an array or something, so that i can match it with the allowed list of cars.

Comment: In that case you probably don't want to store any values. You need to recalculate the positions each time.

Comment: Without knowing what libraries/tools you're using it's almost impossible to say. Is this a personal project? If you have the full code on something like github, I'll have a look. It's beyond the scope of both this question and SO though.

Comment: I can get the updated position and identity of the cars through real-time tracking. I have the coordinates of the region near the gates. Now if the car of a specific identity reaches near the gate, then the gate will open. For doing that, how should i proceed? If you can provide some insights, it will be really great.

Comment: Its my personal project. I can share you the codes. Can u give your details?

Comment: @HarikrishnanR facingBackwards on github/bitbucket/gitlab